# How to prevent my nav menu from covering my website content in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My current nav menu covers my website content when I shrink my screen to mobile. Also, it has scrollable links with each menu item, so whenever I click an option, it will scroll down to that section on the website.

My problem is that my heading for example "Section 1" gets covered by my menu.

here is my current code for my @media and it stacks each menu item on top of each other.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .menu-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    height: 5px;
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML for the first section

```
<body>
    <header class="page__header">
      <nav class="navbar__menu">
        <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
        <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <header class="main__hero">
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
      </header>

I

    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="active">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi
          fermentum metus faucibus
        </p>

        <p>
          Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar
          gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam.
          Cras eu tincidunt arcu,
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Is there a simple fix to make sure my menu pushes any HTML content below it?

Here is how I created my nav menu with Javascript

```
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const items = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4"];

items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const el = document.createElement("a");
  el.innerText = item;
  el.classList.add("menu-items");
  el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
  el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;
  navList.appendChild(el);
});
```

Here's the CSS for navbar and page header

```
.navbar__menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar__menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease 0.3s all;
}

/* Header Styles */
.page__header {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the snippet of code where you menu (the item that has the class .menu-items is included?) .. Do you have your menu in a container that has absolute or fixed positioning?

Comment: I just updated it to show I created my nav using Javascript. Is that enough or do you need anything else?

Comment: Yes, where is the element `#navbar__list`?

Comment: I updated the code again, so you can see it's listed above the section tag. I don't have any CSS applied to that id

Comment: The problem is probably not the `menu-items` class. It looks fine. It is probably in the styling of the `.page__header` or `.navbar__menu` class. May I suggest you put your code in a snippet using `Ctrl-M` or clicking on the snippet icon?

Comment: I updated the code again at the bottom. I'm not sure what you mean with the snippet thing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `.page_header`. It has a `position: fixed`. That will cause your div and all contents in it to show above the rest of the page. Why? [This is an excellent guide to CSS positioning.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

To solve your issue, it really is dependent on how you want your design to look.

- You can move your `<ul id="navbar__list"></ul>` outside of the header.
- You can change the `.page__header` class to be statically positioned under the `@media` query. That way it is fixed on large screens and normal on smaller ones.
- You can consider leaving it as is (I see many mobile apps using that design, its not surprising), but have the menu toggle-able (show/hide based on a button in the nav bar), and when an item in the menu is clicked, the menu is hidden.